# How I can transform a stored procedure to a view?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure which pulls data from 4 tables and ranks them by 4 columns, but I need a view with the same result (of course without parameter). Is this possible? I know that I can not use a temp table in view, any solution?!

```
ALTER PROC pr_GetChildrenByPersonID
    @pePersonIDs varchar(8000)
AS
    SELECT 
        *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pbsPersonID ORDER BY psbPersonSiblingID ASC) AS CustomRank
    INTO 
        #TempPersonSibling
    FROM 
        PersonSibling
    WHERE 
        pbsSiblingTypeID = 2
        AND pbsPersonID IN (SELECT item 
                            FROM dbo.fn_ParseStrListIdentity(@pePersonIDs, ','))

    SELECT
        pePersonID,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsName 
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 1), '') AS ChildrenName1,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsAge  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 1), '') AS ChildrenAge1,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPlaceOfBirth)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 1), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfBirth1,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPresentStay)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 1), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfResidence1,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsName 
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 2), '') AS ChildrenName2,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsAge  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 2), '') AS ChildrenAge2,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPlaceOfBirth)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 2), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfBirth2,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPresentStay)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 2), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfResidence2,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsName 
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 3), '') AS ChildrenName3,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsAge  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 3), '') AS ChildrenAge3,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPlaceOfBirth)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 3), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfBirth3,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPresentStay)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 3), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfResidence3,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsName 
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 4), '') AS ChildrenName4,
        ISNULL((SELECT pbsAge  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 4), '') AS ChildrenAge4,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPlaceOfBirth)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 4), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfBirth4,
        ISNULL((SELECT dbo.fn_GetCountry(pbsPresentStay)  
                FROM #TempPersonSibling   
                WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  
                  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID 
                  AND CustomRank = 4), '') AS ChildrenCountryOfResidence4
    FROM 
        Person
    WHERE 
        pePersonID IN (SELECT item 
                       FROM dbo.fn_ParseStrListIdentity(@pePersonIDs, ','))
```

Comment: 1) never use SELECT * as your tables may change. 2) are you asking for the syntax to create a view? 3) this proc is hideous for starters and subqueries in your select statement like this is hideos. 4) create a table to store this info if this is used often and you will save performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) instead of a temporary table, and use the CTE where you are using the temporary table now.

Like so:

```
WITH 
    TempPersonSibling AS (
        -- the select statement that creates the temp table here
        -- without the INTO clause
    )
SELECT
    pePersonID,
    ISNULL((SELECT pbsName FROM TempPersonSibling WHERE pbsSiblingTypeID = 2  AND pbsPersonID = pepersonID AND CustomRank = 1),'') AS ChildrenName1,
    -- ..., rest of the query is similar
FROM
    Person
WHERE
    -- ...
```

This way you can create a single query and package that in your view.